# Iterating a set using c:foreach and passing that variable as key to map in c:foreach items

Tags: foreach, jstl

```
`<c:forEach var="keyword" items="${keywords}">`         
`<c:set var="test1">${keyword}</c:set>`         
 `<c:out value="${bulkAssayDetails[test1]}" />`              
`<c:forEach var="assaydetails" items="${bulkAssayDetails[test1]}"> `     

`</c:forEach>'
`</c:forEach>`
```

`${keywords}` is a set
in c:out i am able to print the value 
for 2nd c:forEach getting the below error `javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;`

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: i have a set of keywords i am iterating those keywords and when i am passing the keyword as key to map of bulkAssayDetails i am getting the error Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in <forEach>            I checked for the length of the map it is not empty and in c:out i passed a key to bulkAssayDetails  and i am able to get the value.Not understanding the cause of ther error

Comment: can you update your question and share more code

Comment: c:out outside the second c:foreach is getting printed where as the jsp execution is failing for the second for loop even though the map value for the key test1 is present not understanding the reason

Comment: what this the display of your <c:out /> ?

Comment: `test1` is useless. Use `keyword` instead. You're trying to iterate through `bulkAssayDetails[test1]`, but it's probably not a collection or array. Since you didn't post the complete exception, and since you didn't post the code defining and populating this map, we can't help more.

Comment: it prints an object DetailsVO@2f439dc

Comment: So, how could you iterate through a DetailsVO? It's not a collection. It's just an object.

Comment: as i said ${bulkAssayDetails[test1]} should be an Array if you want to iterate it..

Comment: `<%`                
`java.util.Set<String> t=new java.util.HashSet<String>();`            
`t.add("t1");`        
`t.add("t2");`                        
`t.add("t3");`                            
`request.setAttribute("t", t);`              
`java.util.Map<Object,Object> map = new java.util.HashMap<Object,Object>();`              
`map.put("t1","tr");`         
`map.put("t2","tr");`                 
`map.put("t3","tre");`               
`request.setAttribute("MyMap", map);`          
`%>`

Comment: `<c:forEach items="${t}" var="test">`      
  `<c:forEach items="${MyMap[test]}" var="t1">`         
  `${t1}`                
`</c:forEach>`                 
    `</c:forEach>`  this sample code is working the same implementation is not working for my code

Comment: share your implementation..